# Xcode6-Beta crashing when trying to embed a view controller in a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am quite new to programming for iOS, and I'm just trying to go through the Swift "translation" of Apple's To-do list app tutorial (original found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ , Swift version found here: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/developing-ios8-apps-using-swift-create-a-to-do-application/).

My problem arises already when setting up views and view controllers in the storyboard. When I get to step 1 under the subtitle (**EDIT**: Wrong step in the original post) "ViewController Navigation Bar" (Select the ViewController and in the menu go to Editor > Embed > Navigation Controller) Xcode6-Beta crashes immediately. I have tried this several times, and the crash happens every time, with the same crash report.

Reading the crash report i found this under "Details"

```
castedInstance should be an instance inheriting from IBCocoaTouchStoryboardShowSegue, but it is IBCocoaTouchStoryboardShowDetailSegue
```

Is this a known problem with a known fix?

Comment: File a bug with Apple, so they're aware and can fix it. http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Have you restarted xcode?

Comment: Plenty of times. Have recreated the crash ~10 times. But I noticed now that I mentioned the wrong step in the tutorial above. Editing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular crash can be avoided by not doing the previous step to connect the 'Add' button to the View Controller (the two steps just before the one causing the crash). Don't do these steps until you've embedding the navigation controller:

> To configure the add button:
>
> 1. Control drag the Add Button to the ViewController
> 2. On the shortcut menu that appears, select “show detail”

In other words, the steps are out of order.

Also, I'd recommend moving the View Controller to the right side of the Table View controller to correspond to the actual flow of control.

That tutorial has other challenges as well. There is [a link](https://github.com/shivanarrthine/Todo-List-iOS-App-using-Swift/archive/master.zip) at the end of the tutorial where you can download the completed project. That code appears to work. The tutorial seems to have several steps out of sequence with vague or incomplete instructions.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a decent workaround. Do you happen to know the reason for the suggested sequence resulting in a crash? Is it just a bug in the beta-version of Xcode6, or is there something underlying that is specifically preventing this sequence of steps?

Comment: I think that the author created a rushed conversion to Swift from the original Obj-C tutorial without testing the new tutorial. The end product works, but the tutorial doesn't. My guess is that embedding the navigation controller after already connecting an action in the storyboard is not a logical sequence, and the Storyboard app doesn't handle the error gracefully.

Comment: There are a growing number of Swift tutorials available, you just happened to choose an untested one. [Here's a similar one](http://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) on building a table that worked for me.